# Proving a trigonometric relation using circle properties

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles

[image]

Hi, I've been having trouble with this question, and would really like some help.

What I've done so far is applied the cosine rule in the triangle PQR to find that $PR^2=a^2+c^2+2ac\cos\theta$.

What do I do from here?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I know of the circle properties, in that opposite angles are supplementary for example, but how do I derive the LHS of the required solution?

Comment: Start with https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Opposite_Angles_of_Cyclic_Quadrilateral or http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/maths/geometry/circles2hirev6.shtml

Comment: I know about this property already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the following construction helps.

[image]

The blue line is the diameter.

The green line is also a diameter.

The yellow-marked angle = $\theta$ (angle in the same segment)

The square root of the RHS of the to-be-shown = the length of the red line.

Consider the triangle formed by the black, red, green lines.

Comment: OH! Thankyou, I understand now, but I still wish to understand mathlove's proof.

Comment: @hello321 Glad to hear that.

Answer (score 1):

Since the diameter $D$ of the circle is $QS=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, which means that the diameter of the circumscribed circle of $\triangle PSR$ is $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$, using [the law of sines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines) for $\triangle PSR$, we have
$$\frac{PR}{\sin\theta}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\Rightarrow PR=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sin\theta.$$

So, we have
$$(PR^2=)\ \ \ (a^2+b^2)\sin^2\theta=a^2+c^2+2ac\cos\theta.$$

Comment: Could you please clarify further to why PR/sin(-) = D?

Comment: @mathlove, Using http://www.bbc.co.uk/schools/gcsebitesize/maths/geometry/circles2hirev5.shtml, $QS$ is a diameter of the circle, fine. But, how $PR$ and $QS$ are linked ?

Comment: @hello321: The diameter of the circumscribed circle of $\triangle PSR$ is $QS$. So, I used the law of sines for $\triangle PSR$.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: I needed to write more. Is that clear now?

Comment: I understand Mick's diagram, but I don't understand what's happening here.

So, for strictly △PSR it is PR/sinθ equals what exactly?

Comment: By the law of sines, $PR/\sin\theta$ equals the diameter of the circumscribed circle of $\triangle PSR$, which is $QS=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$. So, we have $PR/\sin\theta=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$.

Comment: @mathlove, Good job.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: But the only problem I have with that is, the diameter isn't anywhere on the triangle PSR.

Comment: Does Mick's diagram (answer below) portray what you're trying to say?

Comment: @hello321: What we need is the diameter of the circumscribed circle of $\triangle PSR$, which is the diameter of the circle we see. There is no need that the diameter is on the triangle.